# Values being passed into a function are recognised when I print them out in that function, but don't seem to be recognised if I run an if statement?

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and have an assignment to write a Slot Machine programme using structs. I am nearing the end of the code and everything is working fin apart from this one seemingly simple fuction:

```
float NewCred(){
printf("%s %s %s", sm.fruit1.face, sm.fruit2.face, sm.fruit3.face);
if(sm.fruit1.face == sm.fruit2.face && sm.fruit2.face == sm.fruit3.face){
    printf("\nFULL HOUSE!!! You win %.2f more credits!\n", bet);
    cred += (bet);
}

else if(sm.fruit1.face == sm.fruit2.face || sm.fruit2.face == sm.fruit3.face || sm.fruit1.face == sm.fruit3.face){
    printf("\nHalf House! You win %.2f more credits!\n", bet/2);
    cred += (bet/2);
}

else{
    printf("\nUnlucky! You lose %.2f credits...\n", bet);
    cred -= bet;
}

return cred;
}
```

The first printf line was just a test to see if the strings for sm.fruit[x].face had been passed into the function, whcih they had. However, no matter what the three values for  sm.fruit[x] are, the function always executes the final else statement and I cannot figure out why.

Thank you for any help in advance.

```
OUTPUT:

ORANGE PEAR ORANGE
Unlucky! You lose 8.00 credits...
You now have 2.00 credits.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you cannot use `==` to compare values of C strings. The proper way of doing it is [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html).

Instead of this

```
sm.fruit1.face == sm.fruit2.face
```

you need to write this:

```
strcmp(sm.fruit1.face, sm.fruit2.face) == 0
```

`strcmp` returns a negative number when the first string is ahead of the second string in lexicographic order, and a positive number when it is behind it. When the two strings are equal, zero is returned. That is the reason behind the `== 0` part of the equality check. You can use `!strcmp(a, b)` as a shortcut as well.

Comment: Can't believe this! I've been using strcmp throughout the whole programme and I don't know why it didn't cross my mind here.

Thank you!